# Compare method is not called when sorting a listview

Tags: java, android, comparator

I have a custom ArrayAdapter and at some point I call `super.sort(new MyComparatorB(orderType, context));` but the compare(DeviceB lhs, DeviceB rhs) method implemented in MyComparatorB is never called and the next instruction is executed normally... What can be the problem?

**UPDATE**

**MyComparatorB**

```
public class MyComparatorB implements Comparator<DeviceB> {

private String orderType;
private Context cont;

public MyComparatorB(String type, Context cont) {

    this.orderType = type;
    this.cont = cont;


}

public int compare(DeviceB lhs, DeviceB rhs) {

    int res = 0;
    if (orderType.equals(cont.getString(R.string.alpha_text))) {
        res = (lhs.getName()).compareTo(rhs.getName());
    }
    else if (orderType.equals(cont.getString(R.string.lastAct_text))) {
        res = (rhs.getTime().getTime()).compareTo(lhs.getTime().getTime());
    }
    return res;
}

}
```

**DeviceBAdapter**

```
public class DeviceBAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DeviceB> implements Filterable {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<DeviceB> allDev;
private ArrayList<DeviceB> dev;
//...

public DeviceBAdapter(Context context, BliveAPI blapi) {
    super(context, R.layout.sensor_row_state_list);
    this.context = context;
    this.bliveapi = blapi;
    this.allDev = allDevToArrayList();
    this.dev = new ArrayList<DeviceB>(allDev);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
}


public void sort(String s) {

    super.sort(new MyComparatorB(s,context));
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
//...
}
```

**MyActivity**

```
//...
myDevAdapter.sort(getString(R.string.alpha_text));
//...
```

Comment: Can you give us more information.  I'd like to see some code please.

Answer (score 0):

Troubleshooting:

Try adding `@Override` before `public int compare(DeviceB lhs, DeviceB rhs)`

This should kick a warning/error if you are not infact overriding the compare method in *Comparator*